# "Access denied" error when running a process from a UWP app

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-10

**Question**: In my following case, how can I use [allowElevation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/packaging/app-capability-declarations) capability from a UWP app to execute code with elevated privileges on my Windows 10 desktop with the 1809 update. [This](https://stefanwick.com/tag/allowelevation/) good article from Stefan Wick explains a similar use of such a capability from UWP app to a WPF app but in my case I'm using a Class Library instead of an exe.

**Details**: In my UWP project in VS2019, I've added [.NET Standard](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/net-standard) Class Library project. My one UWP method is calling following method of my class library project. But due to Sandbox nature of UWP - as expected - the app is throwing `Access denied` error at line `Process.Start()` of the code.

```
public void Process_Start_Test()
{
   using (Process myProcess = new Process())
   {
       myProcess.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
       myProcess.StartInfo.FileName = @"C:\DotNET2019\UWP\TestFolder\MyExeApp.exe";
       myProcess.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
       myProcess.Start(); //Access denied error here
   }
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure this is not allowed- also it's super unnecessary isn't it? You could possibly prompt the user to open an application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't call `Process.Start` from a .NET Standard library that is referenced by your sandboxed UWP app.

You need to create an actual elevated *process* (`.exe`) that calls `Process.Start` as Stefan's blog post explains.

The full-trust `.exe` may of course reference your class library where the `Process_Start_Test()` is defined, but the method has to be called from the full-trust process regardless of whether it's defined in a library.

Comment: Yours is a well explained (and to the point) response (thank you). More importantly you completely understood my question/issue.