# C# Access Denied UWP

Tags: c#, .net, uwp

I tried to run a Console app with arguments like this

```
public void ExecuteCommand(String command)
        {
            Process p = new Process();
            ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo();
            startInfo.FileName = "cmd.exe";
            startInfo.Arguments = @"/k " + command; // cmd.exe spesific implementation
            p.StartInfo = startInfo;
            p.Start();
        }

private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            ExecuteCommand($@"C:\Users\conta\Desktop\Project1.exe {Username.Text} {getdif()}");
        }
```

First I Searched and found how to even run a program but for some reason /c doesn't work and the console window instantly disappear so I used /k so I could see the console window and it said access denied that's the problem how do I fix that? I searched and found out that you cant give UWP application admin permission is there any way to fix that?

Comment: Have you try the command directly in a shell?

Comment: Yes I tried it works

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Access denied" error when running a process from a UWP app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56636042/access-denied-error-when-running-a-process-from-a-uwp-app)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since uwp is sandboxed, `Process.start()` is not supported in uwp. If you want to launch an exe file from uwp app, I suggest you could use [FullTrustProcessLauncher.LaunchFullTrustProcessForCurrentAppAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.fulltrustprocesslauncher.launchfulltrustprocessforcurrentappasync?view=winrt-20348) to do this.

Please refer to the following steps to do this.

1. Right click project->Add reference->Universal Windows-> Extensions->`Windows Desktop Extensions for the UWP`
2. Right click Assets folder->Add-> existing item-> your .exe file
3. Add the `windows.fullTrustProcess` extension in Package.appxmanifest like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.applicationmodel.fulltrustprocesslauncher?view=winrt-20348#remarks).

Package.appxmanifest:

```
<Package xmlns=http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10
….
    xmlns:desktop="http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/desktop/windows10"
    xmlns:rescap=http://schemas.microsoft.com/appx/manifest/foundation/windows10/restrictedcapabilities
IgnorableNamespaces="uap mp">
  ...
  
<Applications>    
<Application Id="App"..>
      ..  
      <Extensions>
          <desktop:Extension Category="windows.fullTrustProcess" Executable="Assets\filename.exe" />         
        </Extensions>    
</Application>
</Applications>

<Capabilities>
    <Capability Name="internetClient" />
    <rescap:Capability Name="runFullTrust"/>
</Capabilities>
</Package>
```

Usage:

```
private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            await FullTrustProcessLauncher.LaunchFullTrustProcessForCurrentAppAsync();
       }
```

Comment: When I click the button the application instantly close

Comment: In debug, it returns exception user unhandled

Comment: What do you mean "instantly close"? Did the exe not run when you click the button?

Comment: yes exe didn't run and uwp app itself crashes